# How to solve the problem, related to the lack of visibility of the bean?

Tags: java, spring, oop

I'm writing an api in which I wanted to check the performance of the registration, while the application does not want to start because it does not see Bean -> PasswordEncoder.

Do you have any idea what I can do to make it work?

**Problem**:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.socialplatform.service.AuthorizationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.`

***My classes:***

**SecuritySettings**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecuritySettings extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   
/* base class security, provides all the default security configuration  
which i can override and customize */

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()                                   
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authorization/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I tried rebuilding the project, and maven.

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? If you don't, do you have `ComponentScan` annotation, which include this class location?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Spring Boot project, one easy way to fix the issue is to put this class under the same package as your main class. It works because the @SpringBootApplication implies the @Configuration and @ComponentScan annotations.

If this is not a SpringBoot project, you have to put the bean in the configuration class. This is a class annotated with @Configuration.